# Remove key/value pair from array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

Suppose I have an array of hashes

```
a = [
  {'id'=>'1','imageUrl'=>'abc','name'=>'x','age'=>'20'},             
  {'id'=>'2','imageUrl'=>'efg','name'=>'y','age'=>'30'},
  {'id'=>'3','imageUrl'=>'hij','name'=>'z','age'=>'40'}
]
```

What can be the fastest way to remove the key 'name' and 'age' and their corresponding value from all hashes in the array?

Basically how can I remove multiple key/value pairs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
a = [
  {'id'=>'1','imageUrl'=>'abc','name'=>'x'},             
  {'id'=>'2','imageUrl'=>'efg','name'=>'y'},
  {'id'=>'3','imageUrl'=>'hij','name'=>'z'}
]

a.each { |h| h.delete("name") }

p a # => [{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}, {"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}, {"id"=>"3", "imageUrl"=>"hij"}]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but after running the code, the hashes don't contain `name` keys anymore: `p a` `# => [{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}, {"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}, {"id"=>"3", "imageUrl"=>"hij"}]`

Comment: Sorry, should be `=> ["x", "y", "z"]` because `Hash#delete` [return deleted value](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete).

Comment: `a.map { |h| h.delete("name"); h }` works though. This version is not Rails-dependent.

Comment: Aggree! But still - in my understanding of the question was "how to delete keys with their values from all hashes", so later in code, when `a` is used, it consists "cleaned" hashes.

Comment: This answer is correct, downvotes should be removed!

Comment: There is not reason to use `map`. Use `each`. That is the cause of controversy.

Comment: Indeed, this is perfectly valid and probably the best answer. Although I don't understand why you used `map` instead of `each` (each will return `a` afterwards, which seems more convenient)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - didn't expect this will cause so much confusion.

Comment: Note that using `map` not only is confusing, but also worsens performance by creating new arrays. You shouldn't use it unless you are using the output array.

Comment: Aggree - I didn't take performance under consideration for such a small example. Hope updated answer will decrease confusion!

Comment: It is not just one key/value pair I would like to delete. I could be many.

Here you are only deleting "name". Assuming there are a lot of key/value pairs I don't need

Comment: @PawełDawczak Your comment still sounds like an excuse. If there is some other reason to use `map` despite performance loss, there may be a point, but you don't have any reason to use it. Even if you didn't consider performance, it is worse to use `map` here.

Comment: @Aditya That is your fault. You didn't give a good example (that represents a general case).

Answer (score 13):

Nothing like benchmarking:

Collected from the above answers: and using [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips)

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def a
  [
    {'id'=>'1','imageUrl'=>'abc','name'=>'x'},             
    {'id'=>'2','imageUrl'=>'efg','name'=>'y'},
    {'id'=>'3','imageUrl'=>'hij','name'=>'z'}
  ]
end


Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("map w/ except!") do |times|
    a.map {|o| o.except!('name') }
  end 

  x.report("each w/ except!") do |times|
    a.each {|o| o.except!('name') }
  end 



  x.report("map w/ except") do |times|
    a.map {|o| o.except('name') }
  end 

  x.report("each w/ except") do |times|
    a.each {|o| o.except('name') }
  end 



  x.report("map w/ delete") do |times|
    a.map { |h| h.delete("name") }
  end 

  x.report("each w/ delete") do |times|
    a.each { |h| h.delete("name") }
  end 


  x.compare!
end
```

I got the following:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
      map w/ except!     8.438k i/100ms
     each w/ except!     8.439k i/100ms
       map w/ except     5.242k i/100ms
      each w/ except     5.469k i/100ms
       map w/ delete     9.840k i/100ms
      each w/ delete     9.810k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
      map w/ except!      1.311B (±25.3%) i/s -      2.994B
     each w/ except!      1.360B (±25.2%) i/s -      3.048B
       map w/ except    423.818M (±25.8%) i/s -      1.238B
      each w/ except    458.859M (±25.7%) i/s -      1.315B
       map w/ delete      1.955B (±24.0%) i/s -      3.982B
      each w/ delete      2.025B (±23.5%) i/s -      4.033B

Comparison:
      each w/ delete: 2024710811.4 i/s
       map w/ delete: 1955349074.3 i/s - 1.04x slower
     each w/ except!: 1360241861.3 i/s - 1.49x slower
      map w/ except!: 1311373772.5 i/s - 1.54x slower
      each w/ except: 458859254.7 i/s - 4.41x slower
       map w/ except: 423818242.2 i/s - 4.78x slower
```

Using `a.each { |h| h.delete("name") }` is the fastest (as pointed in the comment).

Comment: Your last test with `delete`, both are `map`.  Is that a copy paste error or is that the actual test?  That might change your conclusion!

Comment: I'm running the benchmarking again with the right values... update comes soon

Answer (score 2):

For example use `except!` (or [except](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)) method:

```
a.map {|o| o.except!('name') }
```

Comment: Note that `Hash#except!` is a Rails method.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the Array and delete it from each hash:

```
a = [
     {'id'=>'1','imageUrl'=>'abc','name'=>'x'},             
     {'id'=>'2','imageUrl'=>'efg','name'=>'y'},
     {'id'=>'3','imageUrl'=>'hij','name'=>'z'}
]
 => [{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc", "name"=>"x"}, {"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg", "name"=>"y"}, {"id"=>"3", "imageUrl"=>"hij", "name"=>"z"}] 

a.each do |h|
   h.delete("name")
end

 => [{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}, {"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}, {"id"=>"3", "imageUrl"=>"hij"}]
```